# React is picking up the system .env file .. not the .env file i have created in root directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

i am trying to connect my mongodb.
i created a .env with two variable.
i added my .env file in .gitignore .
did the require('dotenv').config() in server.js and db.js.
when i did console.log(process.env).
i expected the values or fields present in .env file to be printed, but instead it is printing the system evn file or some other env file.
Please view the below code file and help.
[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2Fs.png)

```
  ADSK_CLM_WPAD_PROXY_CHECK: 'FALSE',
  ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Roaming',
  APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL: 'true',
  BREAKPAD_DUMP_LOCATION: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Safe Family\\Logs',
  CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: '\\\\.\\pipe\\crashpad_18448_AJTNHHWTGWMFOZKE',
  CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
  'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
  CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
  COMPUTERNAME: 'DESKTOP-9290LK1',
  ComSpec: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
  DriverData: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData',
  HOMEDRIVE: 'C:',
  HOMEPATH: '\\Users\\vishn',
  LOCALAPPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local',
  LOGONSERVER: '\\\\DESKTOP-9290LK1',
  NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: '8',
  OneDrive: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive',
  OneDriveConsumer: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive',
  ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'undefined',
  OS: 'Windows_NT',
  Path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\MinGW\\bin;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\python3.9;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\python3.9\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.1\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\python3.9\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\python3.9\\;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\;C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm',
  PATHEXT: '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL',
  PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64',
  PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel',
  PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6',
  PROCESSOR_REVISION: '8e0c',
  ProgramData: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  ProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files',
  'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
  ProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files',
  PROMPT: '$P$G',
  PSModulePath: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules',
  PUBLIC: 'C:\\Users\\Public',
  SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
  SystemDrive: 'C:',
  SystemRoot: 'C:\\Windows',
  TEMP: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
  TMP: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
  USERDOMAIN: 'DESKTOP-9290LK1',
  USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: 'DESKTOP-9290LK1',
  USERNAME: 'vishn',
  USERPROFILE: 'C:\\Users\\vishn',
  windir: 'C:\\Windows',
  ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: '1',
  TERM_PROGRAM: 'vscode',
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '1.57.1',
  LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
  COLORTERM: 'truecolor',
  VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE: '\\\\.\\pipe\\vscode-git-f2796456c2-sock',
  GIT_ASKPASS: 'c:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass.sh',
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE: 'C:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe',
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN: 'c:\\Users\\vishn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass-main.js'
}
```

root\backend\server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
connectDB();
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`));
```

root\backend\config\db.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("MongoDB connection success");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(process.env);
        console.error(error);
        console.error('MongoDB connection Failed')
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

root.env

```
PORT = 500
MONGO_URI ='blablablabla'
```

root.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
node_modules
node_modules/

/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Storej
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
.env
```

Thank You !!

Comment: can you show me the folder structure and where is your package.json of backend.

Comment: Hi bro, i have attached a image of it now .. please view it .. thanks for helping

Comment: `process.env` contain some default variable about system and os. Try logging `process.env.MONGO_URI` , if you got undefined then tell me.

Comment: also in `backend/config/db.js` remove `REACT_APP` form the begining of `MONGO_URI`. beacause in `.env` file you are setting value of `MONGO_URI="*******"`

Comment: Hi Anurag, i have tried those stuff, process.env.MONGO_URI gives me undefined.

Comment: because the process.env does not have those variables present in it .. which is why i am getting undefined. So that lead me think it is fetching wrong .env file

Comment: Try it `dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env') })`. Don't forget to require path module before dotenv `const path=require('path')`. No need to install since it's a core node.js mondule

Comment: Hi Anurag,
Thank you so much for your time !!
when i opened the project after 2 days, it was working fine as i expected.
I guess when i restarted the project after 2 3 days, got things in place ..
Thank You !!